# Why does the Angular JS Route require you to cite a controller?

Tags: angularjs

Why does the Angular JS Route require you to cite a controller?

Coulnd't you just cite a view and then have the view directive link to to the controller?

Comment: Controller is not a requirement of ngRoute route.

Answer (score 3):

> Why does the Angular JS Route require you to cite a controller?

route does **not** require a controller to be specified.  If you omit the controller it will just load the specified page but you will have limited functionality.

> Coulnd't you just cite a view and then have the view directive link to
> to the controller?

No.  This is not what directives are for.  Quoting from the [docs for directives](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive):

> #### What are Directives?
>
> At a high level, directives are markers on a DOM element (such as an
> attribute, element name, or CSS class) that tell AngularJS's HTML
> compiler ($compile) to attach a specified behavior to that DOM element
> or even transform the DOM element and its children.

...and the [docs for controllers](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/controller):

> #### Understanding Controllers
>
> In Angular, a Controller is a JavaScript
> constructor function that is used to augment the Angular Scope.
>
> When a Controller is attached to the DOM via the ng-controller
> directive, Angular will instantiate a new Controller object, using the
> specified Controller's constructor function. A new child scope will be
> available as an injectable parameter to the Controller's constructor
> function as $scope.
>
> Use Controllers to:
>
> - Set up the initial state of the `$scope` object.
> - Add behavior to the `$scope` object.