# Register a Controller $routeprovider OR on Templates

Tags: javascript, angularjs

The question:
Why does angular make you assign a controller to a route?

---

**My thoughts:**

Why not just have the controller on the template? Specifically the highest level of that template. What am I missing?

Based on my understanding this way makes more sense!

**What I am currently doing:**

When the template is rendered it comes with an ng-controller attribute on the highest level (**I am using this!** ).  Is there something going on under-the-hood that I should be reading?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why does the Angular JS Route require you to cite a controller?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21976266/why-does-the-angular-js-route-require-you-to-cite-a-controller)

Comment: The question: Why do you ask the same exact question [twice](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21976266/why-does-the-angular-js-route-require-you-to-cite-a-controller#comment33301510_21976266)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you declare a simple pair of template-controller like

```
$routeProvider.when('/', {
  templateUrL: '...',
  controller: '...'
});
```

you may painlessly declare your controller in the template. There's no 'under-the-hood' behavior and the final result will be exactly the same. But issues start rising when you need something more complex.

First of all, imagine that your controller requires some condition to be satisfied before in can start.

```
$routeProvider.when('/', {
  templateUrl: '...',
  resolve: {
    //do something before your controller kicks off
  },
  controller: '...',
});
```

This resolve condition might be whatever you want it to be. Say, require user to be logged in. You may handle this logic inside the controller but once you need any other route to resolve same condition you will have to duplicate your code.

Another feature that $routeProvider expose in configuration is controllerAs syntax.

See 'route' section in 'parameters' for further info http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngController